# copy only child elements of svg in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a dynamic svg like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="mysvg" style="cursor: crosshair; width: 1792px; height: 1280px;">
<line id="2014_5_5_14_30_37_Line" x1="100.44444444444444" y1="190.14814814814815" x2="235.55555555555554" y2="429.55555555555554" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00ff00" opacity="1.0" Username="UserName" CurrentDate="30/05/2014" stroke-opacity="1" style="cursor: move;"/>
<polyline id="2014_5_5_14_30_38_polyline" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00ff00" opacity="1" Username="UserName" CurrentDate="30/05/2014" points="268.74074074074076,199.62962962962962,493.9259259259259,164.07407407407408,605.3333333333334,289.7037037037037,548.4444444444445,408.22222222222223,368.2962962962963,334.74074074074076,368.2962962962963,334.74074074074076" stroke-opacity="1" style="fill: none; cursor: move;"/>
<g id="2014_5_5_14_30_43_gRect">
<rect Username="UserName" CurrentDate="30/05/2014" x="866.074074074074" y="164.07407407407408" id="2014_5_5_14_30_43_Rect" width="270.2222222222223" height="168.2962962962963" fill="#FFF" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00ff00" fill-opacity="0.3" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: move;"/>
<foreignObject x="866.074074074074" y="164.07407407407408" width="270.2222222222223" height="168.2962962962963" id="2014_5_5_14_30_43_Rect_f">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" color="black" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 20px; font-style: normal; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">some text
</div>
</foreignObject>
</g>
</svg>
```

I want to get everything inside the `<svg> and </svg>` tags in a string through a javascript or Jquery function.

right now I am doing this:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('mysvg');
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var str = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
alert(str);
```

but this outputs the whole svg element i.e. from "`<svg...</svg>`". I want the output as "`<line....</g>`" in this case. I have tried using `svg.getElementsByTagName('*')`, but I cant seem to get the output i want.

Is there anything like innerSVG available in JQuery or javascript?

Comment: You should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` when debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function svgInnerHTML (svg) {
  // Chrome, Firefox, etc.
  if (svg.innerHTML) {
    return svg.innerHTML;
  }

  // Safari case
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  var str = '';
  var children = svg.childNodes;

  for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    str += serializer.serializeToString(children[i]);
  }

  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('mysvg');
alert(svg.innerHTML);
```

See this fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Um5yf/

Comment: that was so easy. now I feel ashamed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use innerHTML if browser supports innerHTML with svg element, otherwise use XMLSerializer to get the XML string and remove the begin tag and end tag.

```
function innerSVG (node) {
  return node.childNodes[0] ? (node.innerHTML || (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(node).replace(/^<[^>]+>|<[^>]+>$/g,'')) : '';
}
```

Comment: Add explain to your answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10634326)